# Invalidating namespace using simple spring memcached

Tags: spring-mvc, memcached, simple-spring-memcached, ssm

Has anyone tried invalidating a memcached namespace based on timestamp? 
For e.g. I need to have a memcached namespace which is the timestamp of the tomcat server that hosts my API services. I need to annotate my method calls so that the namespace is a variable (rather than a constant) and it holds a timestamp of the server startup.

```
@ReadThroughAssignCache(namespace = "api_divisions_", assignedKey="allDivisions")
public List<Division> getAllDivisions()
{
    List<Division> all = (List<Division>)getHibernateTemplate().find("from Division");
    return all;
}
```

Then everytime the server starts up, the namespace on this method needs to be dynamically set to the server startup time.

Update - i know that there is a roundabout way of doing this using javaassist and dynamic annotations, but I wanted a better approach.

-Gotz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace is always a constant, you cannot use variable.
As I understand you want to create cache key using server startup time.
There are at least two way how it can be done.
First: use `@ReadThroughSingleCache`

```
@ReadThroughSingleCache(namespace = "api_divisions_allDivisions")
public List<Division> getAllDivisions(@ParameterValueKeyProvider long startup)
{
  List<Division> all = (List<Division>)getHibernateTemplate().find("from Division");
  return all;
}
```

Second: use custom [CacheKeyBuilder](https://simple-spring-memcached.googlecode.com/svn/docs/2.0.0/apidocs/com/google/code/ssm/aop/support/CacheKeyBuilder.html) which can add timestamp to each cache key.

Do you need old values stored before server start? If not then simple solution is to always use the same cache key and clean memcached at server starts up.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Well, I dont need the old values at server startup. Having a timestamp was a simple approach to refresh the cache at server startup and let the LRU take care of the rest. But is there a way by which i can invalidate the cache at server startup time using SSM API?

Comment: Create custom spring bean with dependency to [Cache](https://simple-spring-memcached.googlecode.com/svn/docs/2.0.0/apidocs/com/google/code/ssm/Cache.html) and as init-method of this bean set method which invokes [Cache.flush](https://simple-spring-memcached.googlecode.com/svn/docs/2.0.0/apidocs/com/google/code/ssm/Cache.html#flush()). It should work as you want. Keep in mind that in multi server environment, restarting one of the server will invalidate cache of all servers (I assume that all servers use the same memcached instances).

Comment: Yes, all servers use the same cache instances. Will give this a go. Thanks.